# Add tag for Geoinformatics

Tags: discussion, tags

Geoinformatics is the science and the technology which develops and uses information science infrastructure to address the problems of geography, geosciences and related branches of engineering.

Comment: As soon as you have 150 reputation, you can create any tag you like simply by using the tag in a question.  Is there as specific question to which you want the tag added?

Answer (score 3):

I'm generally for it. AGU has a section called *Earth and Space Science Informatics* which used to be called *Geoinformatics*. They may have changed the name because "geo" applies specifically to Earth. I'm not suggesting that's a problem. The meaning here is clear enough.

Comment: Will give the full tags a try. Is it worth adding tags for other AGU "groups"

Comment: @davidv I don't see why not. The list is at (http://sites.agu.org/leadership/sections-focus-groups/)

Answer (score 0):

Note that [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is the main stackexchange site for geoinformatics. I don't think this means that all geoinformatics should be prohibited at earthscience.SE (i.e. that geoinformatics tag is useless here), just that only questions concerning much more "geo" than "informatics" belong here. Those concerning both "geo" and "informatics" about the same, or even focused on "informatics", should be asked on gis.SE, and perhaps even closed as off-topic and migrated away from earthscience.SE. Tag excerpt and wiki should emphasize this.

Comment: Note that GIS and geoinformatics/ESSI are not the same thing: the GIS stack exchange covers only *geographical* informatics, not *geoscience* informatics. There's a lot of geoscientific software that has nothing at all to do with geography.

Comment: @Pont: you are right that non-GIS software shouldn't be so restricted here in order not to violate GIS.SE's scope. But I believe not only GIS is on topic there - I asked there [a question on this](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3608/12768) though.